# Can Chrome open PDF documents in the system viewer app by default?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

In Firefox, when I click on a PDF link it opens my default system viewer (SumatraPDF). Isn't Google Chrome capable of this behavior?

In Chrome's settings, here:

```
chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments
```

I see only two options: **download** or **open in Chrome**. Isn't there any tweak to enable this basic behavior -- to ***open in the system default app*** and to bypass the internal PDF viewer?

I realize that I can always download the document to my disk, find it there and open it in Sumatra if I wish so, but this is cumbersome and breaks my natural workflow, distracting me from what I was thinking about while browsing. Very annoying.